# snegine 2.7.1 - problem duble slash after domain.com//

Tags: apache, debian, php-7.2

i have problem with sngine 2.7.1

All link is https://example.com//example 
This is big problem with connect to Facebook login

I think the problem is in the htaccess file but I can't find the error

Look in my .htacces

```
    ## RewriteEngine ##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Static Pages
RewriteRule ^static/([^/]+)/?$ static.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

# Contacts
RewriteRule ^contacts/?$ contact.php [L,QSA]

# Developers
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/?$ api.php?do=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^developers/?$ developers.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^developers/([^/]+)/?$ developers.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^developers/edit/([^/]+)/?$ developers.php?view=edit&app_auth_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^share/?$ share.php [L,QSA]

# Directory
RewriteRule ^directory/?$ directory.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/?$ directory.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ directory.php?view=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Server:
Debian + apache + php7.2

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Hello! Please state what is your actual problem, what error you're getting and the solutions you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello,
I tried changes in .htaccess - deleting the double // but that doesn't solve the problem.

Pops up when trying to login via facebook error 400 - can't find the page because facebook references example.com/example and I have example.com//example

Comment: ok - i find problem, in includes/config  is error. Original is example.com/ - correct is example.com